# Unwanted namespace attribute added to root child element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, linq-to-xml

I've had a couple of attempts at adding the default namespace to the root, although it also adds the namespace to it's child.  I want to add the namespace to an existing XDocument.

My code attempts;

```
// add default namespace - attempt 1
XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.myschema/schema.xsd";
xDocument.Root.Name = xmlns + xDocument.Root.Name.LocalName;

// add default namespace - attempt 2
XNamespace MyNS = "http://www.myschema/schema.xsd";
xDocument.Element("testFile").Name = MyNS.GetName("testFile");
```

XML;

```
<testFile version="1" xmlns="http://www.myschema/schema.xsd">
  <testResults xmlns="">  <!-- *** Unwanted Attribute *** -->
    <result resultID="abcdefgh" comment="blah blah blah blah">
  </testResults>
</testFile>
```

I would like to know why testResults has an xmlns namespace attribute attached to it?

Here is some test C# code which to test on;

```
XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(
    new XElement("testFile",
        new XAttribute("version", "1"),
        new XElement("testResults",
            new XElement("result",
                new XAttribute("resultID", "abcdefgh"),
                new XAttribute("comment", "blah blah blah blah")
        ))));
```

Comment: Show your code that creates the other elements. The answer should then be obvious.

Comment: Added some test code, I can reproduce this on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't add namespace to XML at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607815/cant-add-namespace-to-xml-at-runtime)

Comment: @NULL Please vote to close this question.

Answer (score 4):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.myschema/schema.xsd";
XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(
new XElement(ns + "testFile",
    new XAttribute("version", "1"),
    new XElement(ns + "testResults",
        new XElement(ns + "result",
            new XAttribute("resultID", "abcdefgh"),
            new XAttribute("comment", "blah blah blah blah")
    ))));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to add XNamespace after the XDocument is produced.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "add a namespace to an XDocument". Documents don't *have* namespaces. Element and attribute names have namespaces.

You would have to change the namespace of every element in the document, and possibly some of the attributes as well.

Comment: I just want to add an xmlns attribute to the root node, all the other nodes should just default to that namespace i.e. have no prefix.  Sorry, you are right I'm using terms Document and all Elements/Attributes loosely, Documents don't have a default namespace.

Comment: You're thinking about it the wrong way. The XDocument class and friends are not a representation of the text of an XML document. They are a set of objects representing the semantics of the document. Setting the namespace of the root node does nothing to change the namespace of the child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
var xDocument = new XmlDocument();
var element1 = xDocument.CreateElement("testFile", "http://www.myschema/schema.xsd");
element1.SetAttribute("version", "1");
xDocument.AppendChild(element1);

var element2 = xDocument.CreateElement("testResults", "http://www.myschema/schema.xsd");
element1.AppendChild(element2);

var element3 = xDocument.CreateElement("result", "http://www.myschema/schema.xsd");
element3.SetAttribute("resultID", "abcdefgh");
element3.SetAttribute("comment", "blah blah blah blah");
element2.AppendChild(element3);
```

produces the following xml file:

```
<testFile version="1" xmlns="http://www.myschema/schema.xsd">
  <testResults>
    <result resultID="abcdefgh" comment="blah blah blah blah" /> 
  </testResults>
</testFile>
```